# Почему значение i случайное?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Допустим пример

Он выводит картинки по порядку из caseURLs, т.е. первой будет: *QpxwUeE* и т.д...
Но привязанный к ней data-id, постоянно рандомный, что делать? Как их синхронизировать?

```
var caseURLs = Array(
    'QpxwUeE',
    '2M07KyF',
    'b94fyvz',
    'RLV6lSe',
    'Af9tMkK',
    'ryqBPpE'
);

for(var i = 0; i < caseURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();

    $(img).load(function(){
        $('#caseContainer').append($(this));
    }).attr({
        "data-id": i,
        "class": "slideRight",
        "width": "80px",
        src: "http://i.imgur.com/" + caseURLs[i] + ".jpg"

    }).error(function(){
        //do something if image cannot load
    });

    $(img).click(function() {
        alert($(this).data('id'));
    }

}
```

Вопрос в том, как бы сделать так, чтобы "data-id" совпадал с номером выводимой картинки?

Comment: А где Вы, собственно, добавляете эти картинки в DOM?

Comment: @AleksG, в DOM добавляют в `$('#caseContainer').append($(this));`

Comment: Что делает `loadImages(curCase);`, что такое `iCount` и `curCase`? Откуда они берутся? Пример должен быть воспроизводимым, сейчас же, если выбросить указанное, то картинки могут добавляться как попало: сначала вторая, потом четвертая, потом первая и т.д. Но `data-id` и `src` совпадают. И какую версию jquery используете?

И вы пример бы `caseURLs` привели бы, а то может там значения случайным образом раскиданы

Comment: @BOPOH использую jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: @LiveD негоже переделывать весь текст вопроса. Во-первых, в новом коде есть синтаксическая ошибка: должно быть `alert($(this).data('id')); }); }`. Во-вторых, код (с исправлением синтаксической ошибки) у меня правильно работает в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmq94uxc/1/).

Comment: Правильно?) Id на половину рандомные и картинки показываются рандомно.

Comment: Что значит "рандомные"? Вы посмотрите - id и src картинок совпадает, а вот порядок рандомный. Почему - вам уже сказали (как загрузились, так и добавились). Если вам надо отображать именно в данном порядке, так и вставляйте не в абстрактный `caseContainer`, а в конкретное место. Т.е. до загрузки создаете контейнер с нужным `id` и при загрузке картинки добавляете в этот контейнер. Тогда и картинки будут на своих местах. Либо вставляйте в DOM до загрузки, а при ошибке удаляйте

Comment: @LiveD поясню: я вижу, что у картинки _QpxwUeE_ `data-id="0"`, несмотря на то, что у меня она последняя в блоке сейчас оказалась. Картинка _2M07KyF_ имеет `data-id="1"`и сейчас оказалась четвёртой в блоке.

Comment: @BOPOH большое спасибо за рассказ про конкретное место, .createElement спас ситуацию. Вопрос полностью решен, всем спасибо, раздал +.

Comment: @LiveD а ведь с самого начала было сказано (и в комментариях, и в ответах), что `src` и `data-id` задаются правильно, но порядок вывода картинок зависит от, как они загрузятся...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значения последовательные.

Но в документе картинки появляются не последовательно, а по мере загрузки: ведь `$('#caseContainer').append($(this))` сработает только когда загрузится содержание картинки. В итоге сначала будут лёгкие картинки, позже «тяжёлые».

Мелкое замечание: `$(img).load()` более [не поддерживается](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) jQuery начиная с 1.8. Вместо лучше использовать [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ([см. фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/g0uy7L87/) с вашим примеро)

Comment: Насколько понял, проблема в том, что `data-id` и `src` не совпадают, а не в том, что отображаются не в том порядке.

Comment: Хотя может автор и не смотрел на них вместе, а просто по `data-id` решил что они не совпадают, т.к. `data-id` случайным образом расположено

Comment: @BOPOH да, `data-id` и `src` должны коррелировать. Это уже к вопросу о внимательности автора. Равно как и по поводу того, что он в получившемся HTML коде где-то увидел атрибут `data-id="XX"`.

Comment: @Regent увидел с помощью FireBug

Comment: @Sergiks, хоть у меня и по-другому, но суть таже, выводил так же data-id только в alert. Работает так же идентично как у вас.

Comment: @LiveD хорошо, на секунду предположим, что там это видно (а класс элемента почему-то не видно). Есть ли уверенность в том, что в `caseURLs[0]` находится `http://gg/privet.png`, а в `caseURLs[1]` -  `http://gg/privet1.png`? У меня в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmq94uxc/) проблем не возникло. Хотя, справедливости ради, стоит сказать, что картинки там используются "лёгкие".

Comment: @Regent, да. caseUrl полностью рабочий. Порядок картинок у меня не  менялся ниразу!! В том то и дело, у вас в примерах он меняется, а у меня нет. Только переменная i при ее выводе.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать чтобы и картинка и ее id совпадали.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $(img).data("id", i);
> ```

Этот вызов не обновляет значение data-аттрибута. Он лишь меняет связанные через jQuery данные. Т. е. последующее обращение `$(img).data("id")` вернёт установленное значение, но `img.dataset.id` и атрибут `data-id` останутся неизменными.